# Symfony bootstrap theme

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, bootstrap-4, twig

How to change default order of symfony form components?

I would like to have following order:

```
{{ form_label(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }} 
{{ form_help(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

Currently is:

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
{{ form_label(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }} 
{{ form_help(form) }}
```

I have tried to modify this file: `vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig`:

```
...
{% block form_label -%}
    {% if label is same as(false) -%}
        {%- if errors|length > 0 -%}
        <div id="{{ id }}_errors" class="mb-2">
            {{- form_errors(form) -}}
        </div>
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- else -%}
        {%- if compound is defined and compound -%}
            {%- set element = 'legend' -%}
            {%- set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' col-form-label')|trim}) -%}
        {%- else -%}
            {%- set label_attr = label_attr|merge({for: id}) -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if required -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if label is empty -%}
            {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
                {% set label = label_format|replace({
                    '%name%': name,
                    '%id%': id,
                }) %}
            {%- else -%}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        <{{ element|default('label') }}{% if label_attr %}{% with { attr: label_attr } %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}{% endif %}>{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? label : label|trans(label_translation_parameters, translation_domain) }}{% block form_label_errors %}{{- form_errors(form) -}}{% endblock form_label_errors %}</{{ element|default('label') }}>

    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_label %}
...
```

But without any success.
As you can see I have changed the order and put the errors in the first place, but still, it does not work and display an error in the first position.

Comment: too many unknowns right now. it's easiest to extend the form theme with your own and then set that new form theme (I believe there's some tutorial for that, take inspiration from one of the methods [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html)). you should definitely not change anything in the vendor directory (as it would prevent you from updating your dependencies, which is baaaaad). I wouldn't be surprised, if some caching interferes here. (twig templates are being compiled into php and dumped into the cache).

Comment: If I set the correct order of these components, then I will import file to my src/ directory. Don't worry :) But still I dont know how to change the order of them

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a custom form theme for this, as [outlined in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#applying-themes-to-all-forms):

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    form_themes: ['app_form_layout.html.twig']
```

Within `app_form_layout.html.twig`, we're going to override a couple of blocks to move the errors in the correct position:

1. We need to remove the default form_error(form) call from the form_label block, otherwise you'll end up with the form error being visible in two places.
2. We need to move that call to form_widget (which is a level up in the form [template hierarchy tree](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#form-fragment-naming))

Untested code example:

```
{% use "bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig" %}

{# this is basically the default form_label block, but with the form_error block definition removed, see line 260 of bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig #}
{% block form_label -%}
    {# I think you can safely remove this if-statement, you currently might end up with 2 errors when you have a form with no label defined. #}
    {% if label is not same as(false) -%}
        {%- if compound is defined and compound -%}
            {%- set element = 'legend' -%}
            {%- set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' col-form-label')|trim}) -%}
        {%- else -%}
            {%- set label_attr = label_attr|merge({for: id}) -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if required -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if label is empty -%}
            {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
                {% set label = label_format|replace({
                    '%name%': name,
                    '%id%': id,
                }) %}
            {%- else -%}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        <{{ element|default('label') }}{% if label_attr %}{% with { attr: label_attr } %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}{% endif %}>
        {%- if translation_domain is same as(false) -%}
            {%- if label_html is same as(false) -%}
                {{- label -}}
            {%- else -%}
                {{- label|raw -}}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- else -%}
            {%- if label_html is same as(false) -%}
                {{- label|trans(label_translation_parameters, translation_domain) -}}
            {%- else -%}
                {{- label|trans(label_translation_parameters, translation_domain)|raw -}}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {# here was the form_errors call which is now gone #}</{{ element|default('label') }}>
    {%- else -%}
        {%- if errors|length > 0 -%}
        <div id="{{ id }}_errors" class="mb-2">
            {{- form_errors(form) -}}
        </div>
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_label %}

{# here, we're adding the form_errors(form) call we just removed from the form_label block, so the error is in the correct position #}
{% block form_row -%}
    {%- if compound is defined and compound -%}
        {%- set element = 'fieldset' -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- set widget_attr = {} -%}
    {%- if help is not empty -%}
        {%- set widget_attr = {attr: {'aria-describedby': id ~"_help"}} -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    <{{ element|default('div') }}{% with {attr: row_attr|merge({class: (row_attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-group')|trim})} %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}>
        {{- form_label(form) -}}
        {{- form_widget(form, widget_attr) -}}
        {{- form_help(form) -}}
        {{- form_errors(form) -}} {# << here :-) #}
    </{{ element|default('div') }}>
{%- endblock form_row %}
```

Comment: It works fine, but on the checkbox, the error is rendered twice. Under label and under help tag.

Comment: Following the logic in my example, you should be able to fix that. I’m not here to write production ready code for you :)

Comment: Always a good idea to attack somebody who's trying to help you. Happy to help. Good luck, @wojaet .